# A function that wraps a value in an object?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a function that takes a value and wraps it in a object with a single property, whose name is provided as a string. So something like

```
let wrapped = wrap(1, 'a'); // wrapped: { a: number }
```

So far the closest I've come is

```
function wrap<T, P extends keyof T, V extends T[P]>(value: V, prop: keyof T): T;
let wrapped = wrap(1, 'a'); // wrapped: { a: any }
```

It's inferring the type arguments as `<{ a: any; }, "a", number>`

The reason I want this is because we need to combine objects a lot in our code, and a lot of our helper functions return just the value, but we need the value as a property of an object to combine it. We can't just use regular inline object creation syntax because the functions are all asynchronous, I'd like to be able to do something like

```
combine(
    largeStateFunction(), // Observable<LargeState>
    wrap(singleValueFunction(), "oneMoreThing") // Observable<number>
).subscribe(state => // state: LargeState & { oneMoreThing: number }
{
    // do work
});
```

Is this even possible without needing to provide type parameters for `wrap`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty basic thing:

```
function wrap<V, K extends string>(v: V, k: K): {[K2 in K]: V} {
    return {[k]: v} as {[K2 in K]: V}
}
let wrapped = wrap(1, 'a'); // {a: number}
```

P.S. Your original code has a flaw: you try to do both constraining return type and inferring it, which usually makes TS go nuts or produce `any`.

Comment: I figured there was a flaw in my original code, since it wasn't doing what I wanted it to :P I've never seen the `in` syntax before, learning about it now. Thanks for the help.